# Funcion para validar si un dato leido es un número

Tags: c, validación, entrada

necesito validar que cuando se ingrese un carácter o cualquier cosa que no sea un número, sea inválido. Este es uno de todos los intentos que he hecho. Siempre tengo problemas, mas que todo porque necesito que el número leído sea entero, para hacer cálculos con él después.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void validar(int num){
    int a=0;
    while(a==0){
        if( isdigit(num) ) 
        {
            a=a+1;
            break;
        } 
        else 
        {
            printf("Ingrese un numero valido");

        }
    }
}

int main() {
   int a;
   scanf("%d",&a);
   validar(a);
   printf("blabla");

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tiene su código ? ¿Muestra errores? para poder utilizar `isDigit` debe incluir `#include <ctype.h>` Desea que solo muestre un mensaje que es inválido o que vuelva a solicitar el ingreso.?

Comment: ingrese un número, o un carácter me manda el else

Answer (score 4):

Para verificar si es un número el que es ingresado debes hacer uso del método `isDigit()` del encabezado `<ctype.h>`. El problema que tienes es que no incluyes en el principio el encabezado de `<ctype.h>`, por lo tanto, no te lo valida.

La referencia de esta función la puedes encontrar en: http://www.c.conclase.net/librerias/?ansimac=isdigit

> ```
> int isdigit(int c);
> ```
>
> Comprueba sin un carácter es un dígito decimal.
>
> isdigit es una macro que verifica el entero c pertenece al rango
>   caracteres de digitos decimales, que depende de la categoría local
>   LC_CTYPE, por defecto, el rango es de ('0' a '9').
>
> El valor de retorno será no nulo si c es un dígito decimal.

El código que te propongo para solucionar tu problema es este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void validar(char []);


void validar(char num[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(num); i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(num[i]) ) {
            printf("Ingrese un numero valido");
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char a[256];
    scanf("%s", a);
    validar(a);
    printf("blabla");
}
```

Con este código podrás verificar si el número ingresado como una cadena de texto es válido como un número. Este ciclo recorre cada uno de los elementos de la cadena de texto ingresada y valida si es un número válido usando la función `isDigit()`.

Comment: Lo siento pero tu respuesta no funciona. ¿Has probado el código antes de responder?

Comment: Claro que si, no respondería algo que no funcionara. Este sería el código del usuario que hizo la pregunta junto la alteración necesaria para que detecte los dígitos. El código funciona y me da el resultado esperado. A ti qué resultado te da?

Comment: si lees con `scanf("%d")` no puedes usar `isdigit` porque entonces ya no estás leyendo caracteres sino números...

Comment: Me funciona el código, pero me deja de funcionar cunado ingreso una cadena de texto el cual contiene un solo dígito. En ese momento al validarlo me lo acepta como un número válido.  Deja e intento solucionarlo.

Comment: Listo, ya está resuelto y funciona.

Answer (score 2):

`isdigit()` es una función que, efectivamente, se usa para verificar si un caracter es un dígito numérico o no... el problema es que tu no le estás pasando un caracter sino un número.

Es decir:

- Si le pasas el caracter `'2'`, es decir `0x32` segun la tabla ASCII, la función devuelve `1`.
- Si le pasas el caracter `'c'`, la función devuelve `0`.

Por otro lado con

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

... lo que estás haciendo es almacenar en `a` un número, es decir, si el usuario introduce el dígito `2`, que según la tabla ASCII se codifica con el número `0x32`, `scanf` lo convierte en `0x02` y eso es lo que almacena en `a`. Fíjate que `0x02` no es lo mismo que `0x32` y de ahí que tu programa falle.

Para empezar, si usas `%d` debes usar los propios mecanismos previstos para `scanf` para detectar si la lectura es correcta o no. Ya que en un `int` **siempre** vas a encontrar un número válido, no puedes hacer ningún tipo de comprobación sobre un `int` para saber si contiene un número o no... porque **siempre** va a contener un número. Si revisas la documentación de `scanf`, verás que devuelve un entero indicando el número de caracteres leídos... si la lectura falla devolverá un 0. En el caso de usar `scanf` hay que tener en cuenta que si la lectura da error los caracteres no se eliminarán del buffer de entrada... hay que hacer la limpieza manualmente:

```
int a;
if( scanf("%d",&a) == 0 )
{
  // Eliminamos todos los caracteres hasta el primer espacio o salto de linea
  for( int c = getchar(); c != EOF && c != ' ' && c != '\n' ; c = getchar());
  puts("ERROR");
}
else
  puts("OK");
```

Si tu intención es usar `isdigit` entonces no puedes leer la entrada con `%d`, sino que debes usar `%c` o `%s` en función de si deseas leer un único dígito o un número completo. Aun así, yo en este caso usaría `getch()`. Esta función lee un caracter y te lo devuelve... pero en forma de `int` ¿por qué? La razón es que también devuelve secuencias especiales, como `EOF` para indicar que no hay nada en el buffer de entrada y que puede no entrar en un `char`... este valor leido es el que debes usar en `isdigit()`:

```
int a = getchar();
if( isdigit(a) )
  puts("OK");
else
  puts("ERROR");
```

Answer (score 0):

yo lo solucione asi:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
int p,n;
printf("ingrese un numero\n");
p=scanf("%d",&n); /*Esto porque scanf devuelve valor 0 cuando el valor ingresado no es del formato solicitado*/
while(!p){
printf("ERROR, no es un numero, intentelo nuevamente\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
}
printf("Es un numero!\n");
return 0;
}

/*Aclaro que esto solo me funciono con enteros, no he probado con caracteres o floats*/
```

Answer (score 0):

> Esta función permite determinar si una cadena corresponde a:
>
> 1. un número entero,
> 2. un número con punto decimal,
> 3. un valor numérico inválido (caracteres, espacios, etc.).

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <ctype.h>   
#include <string.h>   

#define VALUE_SIZE 256
#define FLOAT_POINT '.'

int numberValidate(char[]);

int main(void) {
    char value[VALUE_SIZE];
    memset(value, '\0', VALUE_SIZE);   /* Digits cleaning. */

    strcpy(value, "55.55");   /* Enter example values. */
    printf("Return: %d", numberValidate(value));

    return 0;
}

int numberValidate(char number[]) {
    int i = 0, x = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < VALUE_SIZE; i++) {   /* If it sure that "number" come whitout spaces, use srtlen(number) instead VALUE_SIZE. */
    
        if (number[i] == FLOAT_POINT)
            x++;

        if (!isdigit(number[i]) && number[i] != FLOAT_POINT && number[i] != '\0')
            return 3;   /* Not a valid number. */
    }

    if (x == 0)   
        return 1;   /* Integer number. */

    if (x == 1)
        return 2;   /* Float number. */

    if (x > 1)
        return 3;   /* Not a valid number. */
}
```